# webpack error 404 but the page loads successfully

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) as soon as I startup the application but contrary to the error message the page loads successfully and the resources that are all appearing successfully. webpack version: 4.41.5

Not sure what could've caused this.

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    widget: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    host: 'localhost'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        use:['style-loader','css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
            }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/template.html',
      chunks: ['widget']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './dist/index.html',
      appHost: 'http://localhost:9000'
    }),
    new HardSourceWebpackPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Comment: a 404 error is normally associated with the url it failed to fetch. What is that url?

Comment: the url it's failing to get is localhost:9000/getrep but the page loads correctly. to be honest it might not even be webpack but I have no idea what could've caused it so this is my best guess.